# Top of Android superscript being clipped

Tags: android, xml, superscript

I tried and searched for a solution to this problem to no avail. The top of letters, such as the tail in a lower-case "d" are being clipped off. Here's is what I currently have:

Codewise:

From the onClickHandler.....

String selectedorder = "";
...
    if (num_players == 3) {
            editor.putString("prefPrefp3_name", child.getText().toString());
            selectedorder = "3<sup>rd</sup>";}
...
        order.setText(Html.fromHtml(selectedorder));

From the CursorAdapter BindView.................

```
        TextView tv4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dspplyrorder); 
        tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(playersCursor.getString(PlayerOrder)));
```

And from the XML, where I'm trying to get @+id/dspplyrorder to NOT CLIP the tail of the "d" in my superscript...................

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/dsp_id"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/dspplyrname"
            android:layout_width="180dip"
            android:textColor="#7CFC00"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:gravity="left"      
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/dspplyrorder"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"      
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/button_toggle"
            android:text="@string/buttons_1_toggle"
            android:textOff="Select"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="myClickHandler" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

I am not worried about affecting the line spacing of lines above or below, which seems to be the most often occurring problem discussion. I must be doing something really dump, since no one else seems to have this problem. HELP Please.

Comment: Note: The assignment to selectorder is NOT as it appears above. It is "3<sup>rd</sup>"

Comment: Perhaps you could include a screenshot from your emu?

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/28/quickly-add-superscript-subscript/) worked for me.

Superscripted text is usually made smaller when the browser renders it, that doesn't seem to happen here so you can replicate that (and solve this problem) by doing this:

```
someTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Some text<sup><small>1</small></sup>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following for your TextView:

```
android:setIncludeFontPadding="true"
```

That should do it. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, but this made no difference. Besides, from what I've read, the default value is true anyway. Just for grins, I tried "false", which did indeed worsen the condition, but "true" did not fix it either.